# Calculating number of non-zero values without numpy

Tags: python

I would like to turn my term frequency matrix into a term weight matrix.
For this I first need to get the amount of non-zero values.

This is the code I tried to do it with:

```
freqmatrix = [['', 'folder1.txt', 'folder2.txt', 'folder3.txt', 'folder4.txt'], 
              ['key', 0, 0, 2, 1], 
              ['chain', 0, 1, 0, 1], 
              ['mouse', 1, 0, 3, 1], 
              ['door', 3, 2, 0, 1]]

n = 0
for line in freqmatrix:
    if i > 0:
        n = n+1
    else:
        pass
```

i being the variable I used for every element of the list.

This however doesn't work since there is also string values in my matrix.

Comment: What is `i`? Please clarify your question and provide a [mre]. What do you expect to happen for string values? Do you skip them or consider them as non-zero?

Comment: I didn't mean that you *explain* what is `i`. It is not defined in your code. Please post a [mre] code that defines what is `i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the strings in your 2D list represent row and column headers. Just ignore the headers of the table:

```py
n = 0
for line in freqmatrix[1:]:
    for i in line[1:]:
        if i > 0:
            n += 1
```

Comment: This is actually exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much, I didnt think of that myself!